# Drm:intel_pipe_config_compare [i915]] *error* mismatch in ips_enabled

Tags: kernel, intel-graphics, intel

After installing 15.10 on my yoga everything seemed to work fine.
But after some reboots i got this message.

I found this report: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1492764

Saying "it disappeared with 4.3.0-040300rc3-generic."

But i cannot start X any more to start the internet connection and download the new kernel.

Is there a workaround to get an X running to fix this?

Comment: I will try downloading the latest rc6 kernel from http://kernel.ubuntu.com/~kernel-ppa/mainline/v4.3-rc6-unstable/ headers...all, headers..generic..amd64.deb  and linux-image-4.3.0-040300rc...amd64.deb on a USB and install it with dpkg -i *.deb

Comment: Installing 4.3.0 rc6 didn't work either, I will try rc3 now as suggested and also 4.0.9-wily

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I reinstalled Ubuntu 15.10 from the same beta image like before and I cannot re-surrect this error any more.

What I did different this time was that I disabled animations with:

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface enable-animations false
```

Then I updated the system

```
apt-get update; apt-get upgrade
```

before I installed these packages that are mainly usually part of kde:

```
apt-get install kate krusader dolphin chromium-browser
```

So it definitely can work wit kernel `4.2.0-11-generic`

Comment: I installed the latest Intel Graphic drive Installer and the problem is gone for me.